# EncodedURIComponent getting encoded again after using EncodeURI

Tags: javascript, encoding, decoding, encodeuricomponent

Im trying to endcode a URL. One of the param value in the URL has **&** in it and hence we are using encodeURIComponent to encode it. After that, we also need to encode the whole URL, and the encoded values are getting encoded again. What should we do in this case?

```
Value to be encoded, encodeURICOmponent('A & B')
encodedvalue = A%20%26%20B
Query param = {"filter":{"ab":{"$like":"%A%20%26%20B%"}}}
encodeURI(param)

finalURL = %7B%22filter%22%3A%7B%22e2%22%3A%7B%22%24like%22%3A%22%25A%2520%2526%2520B%25%22%7D%7D%7D
```

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Only apply the encoding once.

```js
const value = 'A & B';
const param = JSON.stringify({"filter":{"ab":{"$like":value}}});
const url = encodeURI(param);
console.log(url);
```